# Cannot convert to Python object after splitting Cython code

Tags: python, cython

I am writing a code extents Cython with new type. So, I have following code that works fine,

**sample.pyx**

```
cdef extern int create(void *handle, int *i);
cdef extern int get_i(void *handle, int *i);
cdef extern int set_i(void *handle, int *i);
cdef extern int destroy(void *handle);

cdef class sample:
    cdef void *ptr
    def __init__(self, int i):
        create(&self.ptr,&i)
    property i:
        def __get__(self):
            cdef int i
            get_i(&self.ptr, &i)
            return i
        def __set__(self, int value):
            set_i(&self.ptr, &value)
    def __dealloc__(self):
        """make sure memory is deallocated when object goes out of scope"""
        destroy(&self.ptr)
```

but when I tried to split code and write followings,

**sample.pxd**

```
cdef extern int create(void *handle, int *i);
cdef extern int get_i(void *handle, int *i);
cdef extern int set_i(void *handle, int *i);
cdef extern int destroy(void *handle);
```

**sample.pyx**

```
cimport sample
cdef class sample:
    cdef void *ptr
    def __init__(self, int i):
        create(&self.ptr,&i)
    property i:
        def __get__(self):
            cdef int i
            get_i(&self.ptr, &i)
            return i
        def __set__(self, int value):
            set_i(&self.ptr, &value)
    def __dealloc__(self):
        """make sure memory is deallocated when object goes out of scope"""
        destroy(&self.ptr)
```

It throws error like `Cannot convert 'void **' to Python object` from usage of `&self.ptr`. I am not sure why it is not working. Any idea could help at this point.

Comment: You probably either mean `sample.create(&self.ptr,&i)` or from `sample cimport create`.

Comment: Although sample.pxd is implicitly cimported into sample.pyx (if they're in the same directory) so you shouldn't need to do anything

Comment: @ead thanks for your help. `sample cimport create` seems solve the issue but now I have issue with moving class sample to pxd such as moving `cdef void *ptr` definition to pxd produce error in `create(&self.ptr,&i)` statement like `Cannot take address of Python object attribute 'ptr'`

Comment: How does the code look exactly after you move the class?